# Splash screen logo won't display on my phone

Tags: android, splash-screen

I published my app on Google Play today. Now I see that Splash screen image won't display on my Samsung Galaxy G3 phone, in image's place it shows:

> no media.

But it displays on my other Samsung Prime core phone. How can that happen?

Here is the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: i see a logo, its just white..... ---> after looking closer, it says something media... how about you show us your code instead of having us guess????

Comment: yes, but on my other phone it normally displayed.

Comment: show us code :)

Comment: which code to show?